# Graphql contentful query with error 'cannot query field'

Tags: graphql, gatsby, contentful

I'm using gatsbyJS with contentful. When I start to query any contentful content I don´t get the support from graphql. When I start to type "allContentful*" no contentful stuff appears:

[image: No contentful support]

When i do a query, the **query works**. But the underline is red and i have no chance to see which types are available:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be related to GraphiQL cache. Try to clear the cache or open the URL in incognito mode and see if the problem persists

Comment: Oh my dear. Thanks a lot. In webdevelopment it is always the cache^^

Comment: Wow. Cache indeed. Opening in incognito window fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

[image: GraphQL Gatsby Cache]

Just to be 100% clear, for anyone else who gets this issue...

This is the cache which I needed to clear / delete.

Once removed, the new GraphiQL interface / types loaded